# Do these functions have specific names?

Tags: functions

Do these functions have specific names?

1.y=1/(1-x)

2.y=x/(1-x)

3.y=(1-x)/x

They are usually seen. Their forms are similar to the logistic function, but they have no exponential. They are also similar to the odds in probability.

Comment: I find that the third is called reciprocal function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These hyperbolas are translated vertically or horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, they're just translations ("vertical" and "horizontal") of the inverse functions.